# When linux flush tcp send buffer?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, buffer

How could i find when linux  flush tcp send buffer ?
I just know that when send buffer full linux may try to flush buffer.
Is there some timer to flush buffer regularly?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some background information. Normally you don't have to care about the buffering. What do you want to achieve or what problem do you want to solve?

Comment: There is no generic "flush TCP send buffer" in Linux. There can be send buffers at the application layer - which depends on the actual program and programming language used. And there is NAGLE algorithm to combine short fragments into larger - see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).